# How to use "and" with conditions in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a subset of data based on conditions of a certain column in the original data set. It works fine with only one condition (For example, data[TNT]<10000, but it doesn't work if I want to limit it within a range (data[TNT]>10000 and data[TNT]<25000.

```py
#group2= 10k<TNT<25k
group2_b =  data['TNT']>10000 and data['TNT']<=25000
group2 = data[group2_b]
```

The error message is:

> ```
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add parentheses:

```
group2_b = (data['TNT']>10000) and (data['TNT']<=25000)
```

Or use method:

```
group2_b = data['TNT'].gt(10000) & data['TNT'].le(25000)
```

or use `between`:

```
group2_b = data['TNT'].between(10000,25000)
```